# snc singularity is an open condition?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

If $π : X → S$ is a family of complex projective
varieties, such that $X_0 := π^{−1}(0)$ has simple normal singularities in $X$, then all the general fibers $X_t$ have snc singularities at worst?

Comment: That is not correct.  Already in projective $3$-space, a cone over a smooth plane cubic can specialize to a cone over a union of three lines, i.e., a simple normal crossings divisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just posting my comment as an answer.

That is not correct.  Already in projective $3$-space, cones over smooth plane cubics specialize to cones over unions of three lines, i.e., a simple normal crossings divisor consisting of union of three hyperplanes.

Comment: I thought the question wanted X_0 to be SNC in the total space X (not in ambient projective space).

Comment: @ZachTeitler.  I re-read the question, and I do not know why you say that.  The question is whether existence of simple normal crossings singularities of $X_0$ implies that for an open neighborhood of $t\in S$, the fiber $X_t$ also has simple normal crossings singularities.  This does not refer to any ambient variety, but an intrinsic property of singularities.